# while loading external ajax content with jQuery, the tabcontainer inside the external ajax content is by default not visible

Tags: asp.net, jquery, tabcontainer

I want to load a complex ajax form into another file, the tabcontainer control inside the external ajax form is be default hidden, I cannot figure out why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you referring to AjaxControlToolkit tab-container? Most probably, any start-up scripts that are needed for tab-container control to work are not getting fired when you are using jquery AJAX to get that form. You can inspect the response (for the request to get your external form) - compare the AJAX request to normal request to the same form and see what are the start-up scripts that are missing.

I also advise you to share some code so that better answer could be offered.

On different note, my experience is that ASP.NET Server controls (including ajax-toolkit) does not play well in jquery AJAX. They are designed to work with UpdatePanel model. I rather use html/java-script widgets such as Jquery plug-ins for the better control. In this case, do have a look at [Jquery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) as alternative to tab container.

Comment: Hi, thank you VinayC, i am employing updatepanels a lot to realize partials postbacks in my external web form, do you still suggest jQuery Tabs? What would stop the external form to function down the road if I integrate updatepanels and jQuery Tabs? and what is the jQuery alternative solution for partial post backs? I would like to share my code when I get back to office tomorrow, and happy thanksgiving!!

Comment: @appenthused, your external web form with tab-container and update-panel would work very nicely stand-alone. However, issue will come when you try to load that html using ajax in a different page as you are trying to do. The simplest way out here is to use iframe in different page to load your web form (instead of jquery ajax)!

Comment: you do understand my situation here.. But I would use colorbox in the external form and seemingly having that form loaded as an iframe would stop the color box pop up from working.. Is my observation correct? And I do want to use jQuery tabs and updatepanel together a lot, any good sample on this?